# how to do error handling in Nifi Template

Tags: apache-nifi, kylo

I am creating template in Nifi, and then importing them in Kylo. Each template is specific to my business usecase, and they consist of multiple (30+) Nifi processors.

for my unit testing and for some sanity, I am forwarding error relationship of each processor to separate logAttribute.

but when I am importing this template to Kylo, even when flow fails, Kylo doesn't treat it as error, as all errors are going to logArribute.

Now I can forward error relation of each processor within template to single logArribute. And then forward that flow to Kylo's error port.

Is this a right solution? if not, what other developers do? I am thinking, Nifi should have some sort of SINK processor where I am dump all my error relation.

Please comment.

Thanks,

Comment: Importing a template onto Kylo won't throw any error unless the template (.xml) file itself doesn't correspond to the NiFi templating standards/structures. Are you talking about creating a flow on NiFi through Kylo and want to have the failures tracked in Kylo UI?

Comment: I am talking about error flow (the stuff you mention in later part of ur comment). I am looking for some ways ppl r managing in-house templates. I want to see error/failed on Kylo monitoring window, if my template fails while running. error can be due to any one processor.

Comment: I believe Kylo is by default configured to monitor for failures in the flow and report them in the Ops Manager dashboard on Kylo UI.

Comment: Yeah.. Even the doc mentions the same: https://kylo.readthedocs.io/en/v0.9.1/tips-tricks/KyloBestPractices.html#error-handling

Comment: Not exactly. Lets assume we have a template which does this in series (UpdtAttribute->ReplaceTxt->GtHttp->EvalJsnPth) and then again does this in series. So in total,template has 8-10 processors. Now most of these processor have error Relationship.Now If I connect error relationship from those processors to LogAttribute. And then deploy this template in Kylo, Kylo runtime will not know if template actually error ed out.Either,I will have to collect error relation from all the processors to single processor and then mark it as error or something.But this makes template representation too messy.